# Lock a checkbox based on another field

Tags: validation, locking

I have a picklist on my object called 
Type: New / Pending / Historical

when the Type field is set to: New, then I would like to prevent another picklist field from being edited.
This field is called: Graded

I wonder how to best do this. Maybe workflows? I don't think it's possible to lock a field using workflows though. Maybe it's possible using a formula? How can I express locking a field?

Tia.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, in fact the field that I need to lock, i.e. pervent it from further editing, is a picklist.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example based on Opportunity fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume by lock you mean prevent further editing? You can do this with a validation rule. So (pl__c is the api name of your picklist) `ISPICKVAL(pl__c,"New") && ISCHANGED(graded__c)` would be it if I understand correctly.

I've just checked in a sandbox here ISCHANGED does work with a checkbox field.

(Should have done this as a answer not a comment - which I've deleted)

**EDIT:** 
This is a working example based on Opportunity.Type and Opportunity.Stage. You can use `ISCHANGED()` with a picklist:

```
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Upsell") 
&& 
ISCHANGED(StageName)
```

Thinking about this you may also potentially want to look at using field dependencies, but this wouldn't be true security - it would only be enforced in the UI and not in any API interactions:

> https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I have used `ISCHANGED()` on the picklist (sorry, I am not using a checkbox - my mistake), and it does not work. How would I do this using a picklist that should be locked?

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I was expecting the field to be greyed out, but I will get an error message when I try to edit, and that's fine. TKS